# get filters(com devices) using DirectShow

Tags: c#, filter, com, directshow

from [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library) I got this code but **I don't understand**.

This function shall get all the filters(com devices) after its category and it fill it in the **innerlist**

can someone explain in details I have searched about each part all seems for me new 
I don't understand what is **ICreateDevEnum** ,**UCOMIEnumMoniker**  and **UCOMIMoniker**
and **how we get the filters using them**

```
protected void getFilters(Guid category)
        {
            int                 hr;
            object              comObj = null;
            ICreateDevEnum      enumDev = null;
            UCOMIEnumMoniker    enumMon = null;
            UCOMIMoniker[]      mon = new UCOMIMoniker[1];

            try 
            {
                // Get the system device enumerator
                Type srvType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID( Clsid.SystemDeviceEnum );
                if( srvType == null )
                    throw new NotImplementedException( "System Device Enumerator" );
                comObj = Activator.CreateInstance( srvType );
                enumDev = (ICreateDevEnum) comObj;

                // Create an enumerator to find filters in category
                hr = enumDev.CreateClassEnumerator( ref category, out enumMon, 0 );
                if( hr != 0 )
                    throw new NotSupportedException( "No devices of the category" );

                // Loop through the enumerator
                int f;
                do
                {
                    // Next filter
                    hr = enumMon.Next( 1, mon, out f );
                    if( (hr != 0) || (mon[0] == null) )
                        break;

                    // Add the filter
                    Filter filter = new Filter( mon[0] );
                    InnerList.Add( filter );

                    // Release resources
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject( mon[0] );
                    mon[0] = null;
                }
                while(true);

                // Sort
                InnerList.Sort();
            }
            finally
            {
                enumDev = null;
                if( mon[0] != null )
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject( mon[0] ); mon[0] = null;
                if( enumMon != null )
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject( enumMon ); enumMon = null;
                if( comObj != null )
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject( comObj ); comObj = null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [undocumented] managed wrapper over native API, however the API itself is well-documented on MSDN and the interface names have direct mappings.

See [Using the System Device Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which describes the identifiers in question.

> To use the System Device Enumerator, do the following:
>
> 1. Create the system device enumerator by calling CoCreateInstance. The class identifier (CLSID) is CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum.
> 2. Obtain a category enumerator by calling **ICreateDevEnum**::CreateClassEnumerator with the CLSID of the desired category. This method returns an IEnumMoniker interface pointer. If the category is empty (or does not exist), the method returns S_FALSE rather than an error code. If so, the returned IEnumMoniker pointer is NULL and dereferencing it will cause an exception. [...]

Comment: Documented DirectShow is native API and is not available to C# directly. The code you are referring to is using a wrapper to access that. And I would recommend another wrapper instead - http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: what about enumMon what does it do? also what is  UCOMIEnumMoniker and UCOMIMoniker  (replaced in .net 3.5 by ComTypes.IEnumMoniker and  IMoniker)

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? [`UCOMIEnumMoniker` is on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.ucomienummoniker%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and `IEnumMoniker` itself and its role is described on MSDN in [Using the System Device Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).